# Dockerized nginx redirecting back to client instead of proxying to upstream

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a problem with nginx running in a container.
It redirects all requests that are not GET requests. So the upstream servers cant receive any post data.

Below is my server configuration

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    # access_log logs/access.log;
    # error_log logs/errors.log;

    # proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;    


    upstream auth {
        server auth:5001;
    }

    upstream stores {
        server 127.0.0.1:5002;
    }

    server {
        listen 5000;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
           access_log off;
           return 200 "welcome to face4biz";
        }
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    }
}
```

Also here a sample location directive for the auth upstream service

```
location /auth/login/ {
    proxy_pass http://auth;
    # proxy_redirect off;
    # proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name; }
```

Comment: How can I set up the proxy server to proxy without redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out API gateways are only supported in nginx plus